# Test and Prod Version in One Application Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am somewhat new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and was wondering if **I should put my test and prod versions** of my Django app in the **same EBS Application**. Or, is it best to create two different applications? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this is that your `prod` and `dev` environments are still part of the same application, just different versions of it.

Thus I would put them under **one application**, in two different environments.

The benefit of doing this is **blue-green deployment**. Specifically, when you are ready with your `dev` environment to become `prod`, instead of deploying it on `prod` env, you can just use [swap cname](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html) feature to easily change the urls of `prod` to `dev`.

- [Blue/Green deployments with Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html):

> You can avoid this downtime by performing a blue/green deployment, where you deploy the new version to a **separate environment**, and then swap CNAMEs of the two environments to redirect traffic to the **new version instantly**.

Comment: Hey Marcin, long time no see! I see, I've never heard of blue green deployment, so just to confirm: when my dev env comes to a stage that it is ready for prod, instead of re-deploying it to prod, I just point the cname of my hosted zone to the dev env? Thanks so much!!

Comment: @NGI Glad to see you as well. Yes. That's the benefit of blue-green on EB. Just swap CNAMEs. Off course if you have RDS hooked up, you have to take care of that "manually", and cname swapping is only for the EB's url for your application.

Comment: Right, I see. In my case, I have two different RDS instances for the dev and prod envs. So would I have to manually change the RDS settings in my Django app to connect to the prod one before switching CNAME? Thanks again!

Comment: @NGI Yes, but special consideration has to be taken if you have schema change of your RDS between dev and prod. You can read more about how to do B/G with RDS on AWS at the end of [this](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Blue_Green_Deployments.pdf) white paper.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not going to find anyone that says that it is **not** 'best' to have completely separate environments for test and prod, but whether or not the cost and complexity of setting up and maintaining 2 environments are warranted, and outweigh the benefits in your case - that can only be determined by you and your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My case seems to be standard. Will having them in the same application impact cost or run speed/ability?